# Excel VBA: Can I name a range using a formula?

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to name my just-pasted range something unique to I can find it in the future.

The copied and pasted range comes from a drop-down menu, and thus must be modified

```
Selection.Name.Formula = "=""AddSection_""&SUBSTITUTE('Add Section'!D3,"" "","""")"
```

If they select Oil Furnace in D3's drop down, then that section is copied and pasted.  It should be named "AddSection_OilFurnace"

Is this possible?

What I would REALLY love is if I could have a named range that updates based on how many exist before it.  For example, the above would be "AddSection_OilFurnace1" and the next section would be "AddSection_GasFurnace2" and so on.  But I have no idea how or if that is possible haha.  Would it be something like:

```
Worksheets("Add Section").ranges.count
```

Is that possible and how would it go into my naming formula?

I'm super new to VBA so thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Are you trying to (dynamically) **change** the name that is pointing to a fixed area of the sheet, or are you just trying to assign a name determined by the value of a cell **at the time of assignment**?

Comment: A formula cannot have side-effects. It takes input, computes a value, returns a result. The answer is no.

Comment: Thank you for helping!  I am trying to assign a name determined by the value of a cell at the time of assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think YowE3K has the right approach.   I refactored his code because I don't like `Do Loop`.

```
Sub AddName()

    Dim myNameBase As String
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim maxName As Long
    Dim n As Name
    myNameBase = "AddSection_" & Replace(Worksheets("Add Section").Range("D3").Value, " ", "")

    For Each n In Names
        If n.Name Like myNameBase & "*" Then
            If n.Name = myNameBase Then
                maxName = 1
            ElseIf n.Name Like myNameBase & ".*." Then
                arr = Split(n.Name, ".")
                If arr(UBound(arr) - 1) >= maxName Then maxName = arr(UBound(arr) - 1) + 1
            End If

        End If
    Next
    Selection.Name = myNameBase & IIf(maxName, "." & maxName & ".", "")

End Sub
```

[image]

YowE3K Thanks for the help!

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you - I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Comment: @Haley YowE3K pointed out a problem.  My latest update fixed it.

Comment: This still works, but adding onto it, how would I reference this range later?  For example, if I need to clear cell contents, I am currently using selection, but is there another way I could refer to the range?  I understand it is named *after* the code has run, but *while* it's running, how should I reference it?

Comment: Use `Range("name")` will reference a named range (e.g.  `Range("AddSection_test.1.")`.  But while it is running I would set a variable to point to `Selection`.  For instance `Set Target = Selection.Cells`.  From there just use `Target` to reference the original `Selection`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
Selection.Name = "AddSection_" &  Replace(Worksheets("Add Section").Range("D3").Value, " ", "")
```

or, setting it up to ensure that the range name has not yet been used, perhaps something like:

```
Dim myName As String
Dim maxSuffix As Long
Dim n As Name
myName = "AddSection_" & Replace(Worksheets("Add Section").Range("D3").Value, " ", "")
maxSuffix = 0
For Each n In Names
    If Left(n.Name, Len(myName)) = myName Then
        If IsNumeric(Mid(n.Name, Len(myName) + 1)) Then
            If CLng(Mid(n.Name, Len(myName) + 1)) > maxSuffix Then
                maxSuffix = CLng(Mid(n.Name, Len(myName) + 1))
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
Selection.Name = myName & (maxSuffix + 1)
```

This only increments the count if the existing base name has been used before, i.e. `AddSection_OilFurnace1`, then `AddSection_OilFurnace2`, then maybe `AddSection_GasFurnace1` - it doesn't go `AddSection_OilFurnace1`, `AddSection_GasFurnace2`, `AddSection_OilFurnace3` - but maybe it is useful.

Comment: Nice answer.  I hope you don't mind I refactored your code for my answer.

Comment: @ThomasInzina - mine should ignore `eggcarton` when processing `egg` (due to `carton...` not being numeric) and should ignore `egg` when processing `eggcarton` (due to the first 9 characters of `egg...` not being `eggcarton`).  I still have problems processing `egg` after `egg456`, but I doubt whether the user will ever be using anything ending with numeric values.

Comment: Wow you are amazing!  Thank both you and YowE3K so much!

Comment: Wow...who would have thought that this would be so involved.  It's a good thing that this is just a hobby.  Anyway, I think I finally got it. Thanks again.